# Error installing Oracle Database Client 12c: "OracleMTSRecoveryService Control Utility has stopped working"

Tags: installation, oracle-12c, windows-server

The installation of the "Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server" component fails when I attempt to install Oracle Database Client 12c (12.1.0.2.0) on Windows Server 2012 R2.

When installing that component, I first get an error that oramtsctl.exe has crashed:

[image: OracleMTSRecoveryService Control Utility has stopped working]

Immediately afterwards, I get the error message "[INS-20802] Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server failed.":

[image]

It seems that "INS-20802" is some sort of catch-all error, as none of the solutions I found were applicable to the problem. Usually the issues at this point were that the Control Utility isn't found. In my case it is found, but crashes when started.

This is the relevant information from the install logs:

```
INFO: ConfigClient.executeToolsInAggregate action assigned
INFO: Started Plugin named: Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server
INFO: Found associated job
INFO: Starting 'Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server'
INFO: Starting 'Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server'
INFO: MTSInternalPlugIn: ... adding </ouiinternal>
INFO: Executing MTS
INFO: Command C:\Windows\system32\cmd /c call C:\app\lays\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oramtsctl.exe -new    -internal 
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn.handleProcess() entered.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: getting configAssistantParmas.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: checking secretArguments.
INFO: No arguments to pass to stdin
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: starting read loop.
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server
INFO: Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server failed.
INFO: Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server failed.
INFO: ConfigClient.executeToolsInAggregate action performed
INFO: Exiting ConfigClient.executeToolsInAggregate method
INFO: Calling event ConfigToolsExecuted
```

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Same question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772812/oracle-12-c-installation-error

Answer (score 1):

The issue in my case was that a DLL file was missing that prevented "oramtsctl.exe" from running. I found when I attempted to run the oramsctl.exe manually from its installation folder. The missing DLL file was in the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages, which I installed to solve the issue.